# How to compute the mean for each channel in an image in tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow, mean, channel

What is the proper way to compute the mean for each channel in an image in tensorflow?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`tf.reduce_mean()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean) and specify the axis:

> axis: The dimensions to reduce. If None (the default), reduces all
>   dimensions.

Comment: I guess reduce_mean will find the average of every RGB pixel value along the third dimension, that is, R + G + B /3.  so what if want to perform the average of all pixels in the red channel, likewise in blue and green channels. Thank you @Salvador

Comment: @I.Ayoub reduce mean has nothing to do with images. It works on any tensor no matter what does it represent. You just need to find the proper axis, over which you want to calculate the mean. Write a simple tensor on which you can do calculation manually and test which axis you need to select

Comment: `tf_reduce_mean()` does not compute channel-wise mean

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it is using tf.nn.moments

```
def mean(x):
    mm,_=tf.nn.moments(x,axes=[0])
    return mm
```

where axes=[0, 1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

For a image tensor of shape [W,H,3], what worked for me was a derivative of @Rubens_Z answer

```
def mean(x):
    mm,_=tf.nn.moments(x,axes=[0,1])
    return mm
```

This will return a [1x3] mean value tensor.